# Create an enclave in an linux kernel module

Tags: module, kernel, sgx

Is it possible to write a linux kernel module and create an enclave in the module. 
And how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, all enclave operations (those executed by the enclaves not by the kernel creating the enclave) have to be executed in user mode. They will fail if executed in kernel mode.

However, there is a [scientific paper](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?cluster=4644293343437266635&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) where they use a kernel module that communicates with a user space SGX enclave via a Netlink connection.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I see no reason why a kernel module would not be able to load an enclave. All of the "actual work" of loading and initializing an enclave is done by system software anyway. You should even be able to invoke the Intel-provided PSW to do the work for you, just as user applications do.

The code loaded into the enclave however, *has to be* in user mode.